# LEFT JOIN with tables having boolean data producing unexpected result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

A Table_1 with only column BOOLVALUE(int) having records as

1. 1
2. 1
3. 0
4. 0
5. 0

and another Table_2 with only column BOOLVALUE(int) having records as

1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
4. 0
5. 0

.. I am trying to run a query

```
select t1.BOOLVALUE from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.BOOLVALUE=t2.BOOLVALUE
```

and to my surprise output is not what I expected.There are 12 rows with 6 1's and 6 0's. But doesn't this invalidates how joins work ?

Comment: *"doesn't this invalidates how joins work ?"* No, it just invalidates how you understand how JOINs work. 12 rows is the expected amount: `(2 * 3) + (3 * 2) = 6 + 6 = 12`  What, exactly, were you expecting?

Comment: can you please elaborate, Yes I was thinking it should have been 11000  rather these many as all data from table1 should be output but only matchgin from tabl2 should

Comment: All the `1`s in`Table_1 ` relate to all the `1`s in `Table_2`; so that 2 rows related to 3 rows (2 * 3). Then all the `0`s in`Table_1 ` relate to all the `0`s in `Table_2`; so that 3 rows related to 2 rows (3 * 2). Hence `(2 * 3) + (3 * 2) = 6 + 6 = 12`.

Comment: @Larnu  Thank you so much . My bad getting concepts wrong at first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 rows is completely expected as you have 2 rows related to 3 rows, resulting in 6 rows, and 3 rows related to 2 rows resulting in 6 rows; add these together and you get 12.

When you `JOIN` *all* related rows are `JOIN`ed based on the `ON` clause. Your `ON` clause is `t1.BOOLVALUE=t2.BOOLVALUE`. This means all the `1`s in`Table_1` relate to all the `1`s in `Table_2`; so that's 2 rows related to 3 rows (2 * 3). Then all the `0`s in`Table_1` relate to all the `0`s in `Table_2`; so that's 3 rows related to 2 rows (3 * 2). Hence `(2 * 3) + (3 * 2) = 6 + 6 = 12`.

If we add an `ID` column to the table, this might become a little clearer.

Let's say you have 2 tables like this:

| ID1 | I1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |

| ID2 | I2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |

Then lets say you have the following query:

```sql
SELECT T1.ID1,
       T2.ID2,
       T1.I1,
       T2.I2
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.I1 = T2.I2
ORDER BY T1.ID1
         T2.ID2;
```

This would result in the following data set:

| ID1 | ID2 | I1 | I2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 |

Here you can see you have a many to many join, and where the "extra" rows are coming from.

If you `LEFT JOIN`ed on the `ID` and `I` columns, starting at `Table1`, you would get 5 rows, with 1 row having `NULL` values for `ID2` and `I2` (in this case because although the `ID` matched, `I` did not):

```sql
SELECT T1.ID1,
       T2.ID2,
       T1.I1,
       T2.I2
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
                            AND T1.I1 = T2.I2
ORDER BY T1.ID1
         T2.ID2;
```

| ID1 | ID2 | I1 | I2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | NULL | 0 | NULL |
| 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

When you join on a column of which has repeating values the number of rows returned is the product of the number of matching values in the 2 tables.
In this case there are 2 1's in table 1 and 3 in table 2 so SQL returns the 6 possible combinations (2 x 3). As there are 3 x 2 zero combinations you get 12 rows in total.
If you did a cross join you would get 25 rows back (5 x 5).

Comment: I never thought as such.Now that you say. Yes  this should be correct cz I am expecting first row of A to match with only  1st row of B but it is matching with other as well.  Really appreciate it guys. Thank you so much